# how to show comma separated values in form

Tags: javascript, php

I am using coordinator php framework with javascript and ajax. comma separated values is not show but single values working fine . i have table field like (edit_coach = 9,10,11), (edit_depot = 5,Spur,SPJ) and edit_task_type = 5  please share valuable idea...

**database**

```
edit_coach = 9,10,11 //not show data 
edit_depot = 5,Spur,SPJ //not show data 
edit_task_type = 5 //working fine
```

**JavaScript Code here**

```
 function edit_assign_train(val)
        {
            $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>edit_assign_train",
            type: "post",
            data: "atrain_id="+val,
            success: function (response)
            {
                var res = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(res);
                 $('#edit_train_no').val(res[0]['train_no']); 
            $('#edit_depot').val(res[0]['depot_id']+'-'+res[0]['depot_code']+'-'+res[0]['depot_name']).trigger('change');// not working
            $('#edit_coach').val(res[0]['coach']).trigger('change');// not working 
            $('#edit_task_type').val(res[0]['task_type']).trigger('change');//working fine 
            $('#edit_tot_coach').val(res[0]['tot_coach']);
            $('#edit_janitor').val(res[0]['janitor']);
            $('#edit_time').val(res[0]['time_val']);
            $('#edit_id').val(res[0]['id']);

            }
        });
```

**HTML Code here**

```
<div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-right">Depot : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="form-group">



                            <select id="edit_depot" class="form-control">
                                <?php foreach ($depot_val as $list3) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $list3['id'] ?>-<?php echo $list3['depot_code'] ?>-<?php echo $list3['depot_name'] ?>"><?php echo $list3['depot_name'] ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-right">Coaches : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 pt-2">

                        <select class="form-control tasktype-select" id="edit_coach" name="tasktype[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                <?php foreach ($coach_val as $list2) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $list2['id'] ?>"><?php echo $list2['coach_name'] ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-right">Task Type : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">

                            <select class="form-control tasktype-select" id="edit_task_type" name="tasktype[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                <?php foreach ($res_val as $list1) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $list1['id'] ?>"><?php echo $list1['task_type'] ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you show what you get in console.log(res);?

Comment: please edit my code sir and share me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#edit_depot').val(res[0]['depot_id']).trigger('change');
```

Comment: sir comma separated values is not show but without comma separated values show

Comment: hello sir help me